# Add index to FOSUBundle User entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

i need add some indexes to the User entity.

I found this in the doc of FOSUBundle:

> ### Replacing the mapping of the bundle
>
> None of the Doctrine projects currently allow overwriting part of the mapping
>   of a mapped superclass in the child entity.
>
> If you need to change the mapping (for instance to adapt the field names
>   to a legacy database), one solution could be to write the whole mapping again
>   without inheriting the mapping from the mapped superclass. In such case,
>   your entity should extend directly from `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` (and
>   `FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group` for the group). Another solution can be through
>   `doctrine attribute and relations overrides`_.
>
> Caution!
>
> It is highly recommended to map all fields used by the bundle (see the
>       mapping files of the bundle in `Resources/config/doctrine/`). Omitting
>       them can lead to unexpected behaviors and should be done carefully.
>
> doctrine attribute and relations overrides: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides

But I dont't understand what I must do to create an additional index.

I'm using annotation for mapping my entities.

I try it:

```
  @ORM\Table(
   name="fos_user",
   indexes={
       @ORM\Index(name="last_ip_idx", columns={"last_ip"})
   }
  )
```

But doctrine retunrs this:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>     An exception occurred while executing 'DROP INDEX IDX_957A64799F12C49A ON fos_user':
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_957A64799F12C49A': needed in a foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears because you are changing the index of an existing `foreign key constraint` and doctrine rejects to edit it because data could be lost.

I the existing data in the table is not important just run:

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` 
in your from your project root
if it still fails, hard delete the entire table and re-run the command.

If you have already important data which should not get lost you will need to migrate the data using a second temporary table

Comment: I'm not changing any `foreign key  constraint`. Just adding a new index to the table to do more faster queries.

Comment: Yes and because something is linked to that index you are changing the constraint